# Get typesafe config value as Array of Case class

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a conf file as below in HOCON Config format.

```
mapConfig :[
    { name = "AAA", value = "BBBB" },
    { name = "CCC", value ="DDD" },
    { name = "EEE", value ="FFF"}]
```

Suppose i have a case class like below,

```
case class ConfigData (val name: String, val value: String)
```

I tried to get the config value as

```
Array [ConfigData["AAA","BBBB"], ConfigData["CCC","DDD"],ConfigData["EEE","FFF"]]
```

I ran the below code which is not returning the data in expected format. I am getting error as "missed parameter type for expanded function".

```
val config = ConfigFactory.parseResources("config-prop")
val configArray = config.getConfigList("mapConfig").asScala.map (ConfigData (_,_) )
```

How to solve this issue and get the value in desired format?

Comment: can you update with the code of how you created config?

Comment: added config parser code

Comment: Have you considered something like https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig ?

Comment: I didnt try pureconfig. Is it better than typesafe config?

Comment: Long story short: it's a wrapper that takes typesafe config and translate it into case class format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.getConfigList("mapConfig").asScala.map (ConfigData (_,_) )
```

Here in `.map` you are passing config as an argument to `ConfigData(_, _)`, which expects 2 arguments.

I guess something like:

```
config.getConfigList("mapConfig").asScala.map { config =>
   val name = config.getString("name")
   val value = config.getString("value")
   ConfigData(name, value)
}
```

would work better. Alternativelly with https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig you could:

```
case class ConfigData(val name: String, val value: String)
case class ConfigList(mapConfig: List[ConfigData])

pureconfig.loadConfig[ConfigList] // Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures, ConfigList]
```

However, by default it requires some conventions so it would expect your config to have `map-config` instead of `mapConfig` key.